# Is there a way to get the current executor type?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to make a batch insert with the for each method, I get an exception telling me that I cannot change the running executor type.
This is very strange as I have an SQL session so defined:

```
<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH" />
</bean>
```

Either way I'd like to check what's the current executor type to make sure it is a BATCH one. How to do that? I see no method in SQLSession...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `sqlSession` is of type `SqlSessionTemplate` and it has `getExecutorType()` method so you just need to use correct type and have several options to do that

1. inject `SqlSessionType` instead of plain `SqlSession` to the service where you need access to executor type
2. cast `SqlSession` to `SqlSessionTemplate` and then use `getExecutorType`
3. inject `SqlSessionType`'s property use SPEL to the service like this:

`@Value("#{sqlSession.executorType}")
    private ExecutorType executorType;`